# How to add texture to 3D model made in qubicle for export to Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, blender, texture-mapping

Being that this is the most general section of stack exchange and I didn't want to narrow the answers to using Blender I am asking this here as I haven't found a definitive answer - Im a noobie with 3D modeling but Ive done a lot with Unity3D.

I need to use voxel models I have created in Qubicle in my Unity game - in the past I have made basic shapes with basic colors in Blender and just dragged the .blend file into my game. Now however Im having a new obstacle to surmount -

I am able to apply basic colors to my voxel models in qubicle and export them as fbx, or just as a qubicle file for unity. This works however I need to apply textures to my models that will be retained in Unity like this (see the tiles):

[image]

I have never applied textures to a 3d game object before - using qubicle models what is the best way to go about this?

I have heard of importing into blender, however my experience with texture mapping in blender is limited and it has never worked for me. Is there an easier approach? How does one create a texture - is it png?

Comment: This is not the *general* section of SE! [This is for programmers](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Ask a question like this on a Unity or Blender Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

that art looks sick!

Have you tried updating to Qubicle 2, or using a voxel importer such as Qubicle Unite?

I haven't used Qubicle or Qubicle Unite, but once you have that plugin it seems [strait forward](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zV-FrrVPiws).

Apparently this functionality was added to Qubicle 2 though ([according to minddesk](http://minddesk.com/learn/article.php?id=1)). If you're not running that version already, perhaps updating would solve your problem?

On the off chance you are on Qubicle version 2, there are also [instructions](http://minddesk.com/learn/article.php?id=24) available on importing your fbx files and textures on mindesk's site.

Good luck, and again; awesome looking art!

Comment: thank you but taking it back a step - those aren't real models yet - how can I apply textures instead of colors to models I create in qubicle?

Comment: Again, I haven't used Qubicle, but in the [documentation](http://minddesk.com/learn/article.php?id=24), under 'Using Textures' it reads: "If you have exported your mesh with a texture...". Have you checked the export settings from Qubicle? There's a good chance a Export Textures is somewhere in the export options.

Comment: No they don't mean that kind of texture they mean plain colors.